# TFS narrow down number of new work items in menu

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem, tfs-web-access

How can i narrow down number of work items in menu in Team Foundation Server when i am using Team web access?

I need to change work items based on user rights.

EG :

- Users -> add bug, issue
- Managers -> Add task
- Developers -> All

Example of the work items below:
[image: Example of tfs]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is on [Visual Studio UserVoice](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2085675-hide-work-item-types-wits-based-on-permission-se) already a suggestion on this.

The product team responded with the following comment: "We’re planning on making some work item types (like Shared Steps) not visible in the new work item menu in clients like Visual Studio and Web, where they don’t make as much sense"

So you might expect this to be possible in the next version of TFS.